# Length of nested list/array anfularfire 2

Tags: html, angular, angularfire2

I have the following setup in my **firebase project**:

```
- Clients
  - Client 1
     - Name
     - Services
         - Service 1
         - Service 2
  - Client 2
     - Name
     - Services
         - Service 1
         - Service 2
         - Service 3
```

In top of this I have a service which provides the clients to my component, this is my **component** which implements the service:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-client-list',
  templateUrl: './client-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../dashboard.component.css'],
  providers: [clientService]
})
export class ClientListComponent implements OnInit {
  clients: Client[];
  dataAvailable: boolean;
  constructor(private clientService: clientService) {
    this.dataAvailable = false;
    this.clientService = clientService;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.clientService.getClients().subscribe(res => {
      this.clients = res;
      this.dataAvailable = true;
    });
  }
  updateSearch(a: string) {
    this.cientService.getClient(a);
  }
}
```

And this is how I show it (or how I'm supposed to) in my **HTML**:

```
    <div *ngIf="dataAvailable">
<div id="row" *ngFor="let item of homies">
    <span>{{item.name}}</span>
    <span>{{item.upcomingServices.length}}</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Right now {{item.upcomingServices.length}} shows nothing, it just leaves a blank space, I have already tried these two variation but nothing seems to work:

{{(item.upcomingServices | async).length}}
{{(item.upcomingServices | async)?.length}}

The first one gives this error:

```
Cannot read property 'length'  of null
```

And the second one gives this one:

```
InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
```

This is the **service** that I use to retrieve the clients:

```
@Injectable()
export class ClientService {
  homies: FirebaseListObservable<Client[]>;
  subject: BehaviorSubject<any>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.subject = new BehaviorSubject('');
    this.clients = db.list('/clients', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'name',
        startAt: this.subject
      }
    });
  }
  getClients() {
    this.subject.next('');
    return this.clients;
  }
  getClient(id: number | string) {
    this.subject.next(id);
    return this.clients;
  }
}
```

Any Idea of how can I get the length of a nested array inside the HTML, in this case the length of services when showing the clients.

Comment: please post your clientService.getClients(); code

Comment: Question updated with service structure

Comment: try the answer i posted please

Comment: To apply your solution I had to change the type of clients from:
FirebaseListObservable<Client[]> to Client[]. Also I had to delete the ( | async) inside the HTML. And I couldn't assign .json to res because it says Client[] doesn't have that property. It still doesn't work.

{{item.upcomingServices.length}} shows an empty space

Comment: Update: I forgot to use *ngIf="dataAvailable" inside HTML, nut now I get the error: Can't have multiple template bindings on one element, to solve this I used <ng-container *ngIf="dataAvailable"> to wrap the div which has the ngfor but {{item.upcomingServices.length}} still shows an empty space

Comment: Post your updated template code

Comment: sorry my bad,i have updated my code

Comment: Template update, {{item.upcomingServices.length}} still shows an empty space

Comment: wait a sec !!You are returning return this.clients; from the service and there is nothing called clients in the service !!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152081/discussion-between-vikk-and-alejandro-cordoba).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subscribe to the function and add a condition before displaying the template like below.
declare a boolean variable like below

```
dataAvailable:boolean=false;
```

and modify the ngOnInit method like this

```
 this.clientService.getClients().subscribe(res=>{
this.clients=res;//res.json() if it is not json already
this.dataAvailable=true;
});
```

and modify your template like below

```
 <div *ngIf="dataAvailable">
    <div id="row" *ngFor="let item of clients " >
            <span>{{item.name}}</span>
            <span>{{item.upcomingServices.length}}</span> 
    </div>
    </div>
```